# draw a Grid line on each and every baseline and every page (throughout the file)

Tags: grids, grid-typesetting, ltxgrid

How to get the Grid lines on the every baseline and every page, like the below image, is any packages are available to get the desired output?

also suggest How to typeset the text on the grid lines (ignoring Rubber length on equations figures, tables and environments, etc...)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's just too easy in ConTeXt MKIV.

```
\setuplayout[grid=yes]

\showgrid

\starttext

\input knuth

\stoptext
```

[image]